# Clickbank api for getting the receipt information

Tags: clickbank

I have tried creating a small class for clickbank which fetches the receipt information from the clickbank. I thought, it might be helpful for someone. In function get_payment_info($tries, $receipt) tries has been used because clickbank doesn't recognize transaction immediately after it happens.

```
<?php

define('CLICKBANK_DEV_KEY','DEV-KEY');
define('CLICKBANK_API_KEY','API-KEY');



Class ClickBank
{
    /*
     * $tries   how many times to check for receipt
     *          because when you come back from clicbank it sometimes shows it invalid
     *          
     * $receipt 
     * 
     * @return  empty array if receipt not valid
     *          receipt info array if receipt is valid 
     */
    function get_payment_info($tries, $receipt){
        $receipt_info = array();
        while($tries>0 && count($receipt_info)==0){
            $receipt_info = $this->get_receipt_info($receipt);
            $tries--;   
        }
        return $receipt_info;
    }

    function get_receipt_info($receipt){
        $receipt_info = array();
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/orders/$receipt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json", "Authorization:".CLICKBANK_DEV_KEY.":".CLICKBANK_API_KEY));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if($curl_info['http_code']==200){
            $receipt_info = json_decode($result);           
        }

        return $receipt_info;
    }
}

$clickbank = new ClickBank();

$receipt = $_GET['cbreceipt'];

// it will return you transaction details
$transaction_info = $clickbank->get_payment_info(10, $receipt);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works well and I'll use this in the future. Nice work :)

Comment: This is really very helpful. only 1 thing need to keep in mind is that - use latest version in the api. except this , all are ok.

Comment: This is not a question. StackOverflow is not a place for posting code snippets, it's a place for programming Q&A.